# What kind of file formats can Blender handle?

Tags: import, file-format

I've search around to find a list of what kind of file formats  can Blender handle but didn't find any. Does someone  have any kind of list?

More precisely, I've created a voxel model in MagicaVoxel and I want to animate it in Blender, it's a .vox file,  can Blender import those?

Answer (score 3):

search on [bing](https://www.bing.com/search?q=magicavoxel++blender&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=magicavoxel+blender&sc=1-22&sk=&cvid=F5B0F6E5DB4A49128BC49B453B6B3D53) 12.300 results

search on [google](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=magicavoxel+to+blender&spf=389) 36.400 results

search on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=magicavoxel+to+blender) 1.680 results

1. open your vox file in magicaVoxel.
2. export it to obj file.
3. open blender.
4. import the obj file.

[image]

**Related**
[Blender manual: importing & exporting](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/files/import_export.html?highlight=import)

Comment: Blender manual link has moved here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/files/import_export.html

Answer (score 1):

Importing different formats is mainly handled by addons so there is not a specific number of formats Blender can handle.